# populate data on appropriate Section in recyclerView (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerView where i added some sections using this [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2921)

and my RecyclerView is now looking like this [image: image of my RecyclerView]

as you can see that my data is not organised yet, right now my data is on this form :

```
  Section 2015
2016-05-03
2016-04-03
2015-12-03
  Section 2016
2016-05-03
2016-04-03
2015-12-03
```

i want it to be like :

```
  Section 2015
2015-12-03
  Section 2016
2016-05-03
2016-04-03
```

as you can see i want to manage the data according to their value and section's value

this is my MainAdapter Class:

```
public class MainAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<MainAdapter.MainVH> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

List<Data> dataArray = Collections.emptyList();
ArrayList<String> data;
ArrayList<String > sectionData;

public MainAdapter(Context context ,ArrayList<String> data  , ArrayList<String> sectionData   ){

    inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);


    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.sectionData = sectionData;

}

@Override
public int getSectionCount() {

    return sectionData.size(); // number of sections.
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(int section) {



    return data.size(); // odd get 8
//        return 8; // number of items in section (section index is parameter).
}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(MainVH holder, int section) {
    // Setup header view.

    String current = sectionData.get(section);


    holder.title.setText(current);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainVH holder, int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {
    // Setup non-header view.
    // 'section' is section index.
    // 'relativePosition' is index in this section.
    // 'absolutePosition' is index out of all non-header items.
    // See sample project for a visual of how these indices work.

    if (data.get(relativePosition).contains("2015")){


        Toast.makeText(context , "it contains 2015",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    String currentRow = data.get(relativePosition);
    holder.title.setText(currentRow);



  //        holder.title.setText(String.format("S:%d, P:%d, A:%d", section, relativePosition, absolutePosition));


}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {
    if (section == 1)
        return 0; // VIEW_TYPE_HEADER is -2, VIEW_TYPE_ITEM is -1. You can return 0 or greater.
    return super.getItemViewType(section, relativePosition, absolutePosition);
}


@Override
public MainVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Change inflated layout based on 'header'.

    int layout;
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
            layout = R.layout.section;
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
            layout = R.layout.row;
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(context,"Default",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER ? R.layout.section : R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new MainVH(v);
}

public static class MainVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final TextView title;
    public MainVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // Setup view holder.
        // You'd want some views to be optional, e.g. for header vs. normal.

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV);
    }
}
}
```

and this is my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




MainAdapter mainAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<String> mData;
ArrayList<String > mDataSection,RawmDataSection;

ArrayList<Data> managedDataArray;
HashMap hMap;


ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> organizedData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    mDataSection = new ArrayList<String>();
    RawmDataSection = new ArrayList<String>();

     hMap = new HashMap();

    managedDataArray  =  new ArrayList<Data> ();


    organizedData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();


    mData.add("2016-05-3");
    mData.add("2016-04-3");
    mData.add("2016-02-3");
    mData.add("2015-12-3");

    for (int i = 0 ; i<mData.size() && i<mData.size() ; i++ ){

        //spilting the data
        String string = mData.get(i);
        String[] parts = string.split("-");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];
        String part3 = parts[2];

        RawmDataSection.add(part1);
    }

    Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(RawmDataSection);

    mDataSection.addAll(uniqueSet);


  final  List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "ReFreshing", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            Data dataObject = new Data();


            for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {

                dataObject.RowMonth = mData.get(i);
                Log.d("row :" + mData.get(i), " Section : ");


                data.add(dataObject);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mDataSection.size(); i++) {

                dataObject.SectionYear = mDataSection.get(i);
                Log.d("row :", " Section : " + mDataSection.get(i));

                data.add(dataObject);
            }


            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.List);
            MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(MainActivity.this, mData, mDataSection);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


            organizedData.add(mDataSection);
            organizedData.add(mData);



        }
    });

}


}
```

i even don't know where to start so if any body can give me any hint or guidance than it'll be so helpful and highly appreciated by  me , thanks

if my question is not understandable then please let me know i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in a simpler way with the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter).

First create a Section class to group your items:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data for each year
MySection section2015 = new MySection("2015", dataList2015);
MySection section2016 = new MySection("2016", dataList2016);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2015);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2016);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```